# How to find files based on DAY of week in Windows

Tags: windows, search, find, timestamp, file-search

I need to search for files that were created in 2016 on Saturday of every month. 
Is there any method or program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using PowerShell

Open Windows PowerShell and navigate to the folder you'd like to search. I assume you know how.

Then, run the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction Ignore | Where-Object {($_.CreationTime.DayOfWeek -eq "Saturday") -and ($_.CreationTime.Year -eq 2016)} | Format-Table -AutoSize -Property CreationTime,FullName
```

**Please wait until it is completed.**

It will print a list of those files on screen.

If you wish, add `> FClist.txt` to the end of the command! Doing so creates a file called `FClist.txt` that contains the list of all the files you are looking for. You might want to change the name of the file to something else if there is already a `FClist.txt` in that folder.

### Using File Explorer (incomplete)

I just test this in Windows 10 1607:

In File Explorer, navigate to the folder you'd like to search, maybe even the root of a drive. Then search for `created:saturday`.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to restrict results to 2016.

Comment: @AbdolAliE Did it help? If yes, please click on the gray check mark beside the answer.